# c# the inner text is always zero though it has values

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code

```
 spTAC.InnerText = ((Tabn / TinBCalls) * 100) + "%";
```

I debuged that code and the `Tabn` is 204

the TinBCalls is 1162

the spTAC keep have the value 0%

why please? i am going to loose my mind of this thing.

(there are no code executed after that line).

```
<td class="informationTableValue" runat="server" id="spTAC">

                        </td>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to make sure you cast one to double

```
  spTAC.InnerText = ((Tabn / (double)TinBCalls) * 100) + "%";
```

from [MSDN 7.7.2 Division operator, Visual Studio .NET 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  (pretty old and i can't seem to find a recent link but the rule didn't change since 2003)

> ```
> Integer division:
>     int operator /(int x, int y);
>     uint operator /(uint x, uint y);
>     long operator /(long x, long y);
>     ulong operator /(ulong x, ulong y);
> ```
>
> The division rounds the result towards zero...

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli more information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you are trying to divide two integers here?
In that case, I would suggest to try and cast them into float values.

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but a code sample and explanation would help future searchers learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing an integer division, which will always return 0 when `Tabn`  is less than `TinBCalls`. Multilpying 0 by 100 will still produce 0...

You can either change the multiplication order or cast to a floating point data type so that the division will produce a mantissa.

You can also try:

```
spTAC.InnerText = (((double)Tabn / TinBCalls) * 100.0) + "%";
```